# links not working as required when used with reparenting

Tags: jointjs

Links doesn't release off the mouse on pointer-up when used along with reparenting. I am not sure what is wrong and I am still new to joint js.

Code:

```
 window.onload = function ()
            {
                var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
                var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
                    el: $('#myholder'),
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 680,
                    model: graph,
                    gridSize: 1,
                    defaultLink: new joint.dia.Link({
                        attrs: {'.marker-target': {d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z'}}
                    }),
                    validateConnection: function (cellViewS, magnetS, cellViewT, magnetT, end, linkView) {
                        // Prevent linking from input ports.
                        if (magnetS && magnetS.getAttribute('type') === 'input')
                            return false;
                        // Prevent linking from output ports to input ports within one element.
                        if (cellViewS === cellViewT)
                            return false;
                        // Prevent loop linking
                        return (magnetS !== magnetT);
                        // Prevent linking to input ports.
                        return magnetT && magnetT.getAttribute('type') === 'input';
                    },
                    // Enable marking available cells & magnets
                    markAvailable: true
                            // Enable link snapping within 75px lookup radius
//                    snapLinks: {radius: 75}
                });

                var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
                    position: {x: 10, y: 50},
                    size: {width: 51, height: 41},
                    attrs: {rect: {fill: 'white', stroke: '#7E7E7E'}}
                });

                var rectGroup0 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
                    position: {x: 10, y: 420},
                    size: {width: 51, height: 41},
                    attrs: {rect: {fill: 'white', stroke: '#7E7E7E'}}
                });

                paper.on('cell:pointerdblclick', function (cellView, evt, x, y)
                {
                    var clone = cellView.model.clone();
                    if (rect.id === cellView.model.id)
                    {
                        clone = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
                            position: {x: 100, y: 50},
                            size: {width: 51, height: 41},
                            inPorts: [''],
                            outPorts: [''],
                            attrs: {
                                '.': {magnet: false},
                                '.label': {text: '', 'ref-x': .4, 'ref-y': .2},
                                '.inPorts circle': {type: 'input'},
                                '.outPorts circle': {type: 'output'},
                                '.port-body': {r: 5}
                            }
                        });
                        graph.addCell(clone);
                    }

                    else if (rectGroup0.id === cellView.model.id)
                    {
                        clone = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
                            position: {x: 160, y: 450},
                            size: {width: 551, height: 150},
                            outPorts: [''],
                            attrs: {
                                '.': {magnet: false},
                                '.label': {text: '', 'ref-x': .4, 'ref-y': .2},
                                '.port-body': {r: 0}
                            }
                        });
                        graph.addCell(clone);
                    }
                });
                // First, unembed the cell that has just been grabbed by the user.
                paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function (cellView, evt, x, y) {

                    var cell = cellView.model;
                    if (!cell.get('embeds') || cell.get('embeds').length === 0) {
                        // Show the dragged element above all the other cells (except when the
                        // element is a parent).
                        cell.toFront();
                    }

                    if (cell.get('parent')) {
                        graph.getCell(cell.get('parent')).unembed(cell);
                    }
                });
                // When the dragged cell is dropped over another cell, let it become a child of the
// element below.
                paper.on('cell:pointerup', function (cellView, evt, x, y) {

                    var cell = cellView.model;
                    var cellViewsBelow = paper.findViewsFromPoint(cell.getBBox().center());
                    if (cellViewsBelow.length) {
                        // Note that the findViewsFromPoint() returns the view for the `cell` itself.
                        var cellViewBelow = _.find(cellViewsBelow, function (c) {
                            return c.model.id !== cell.id
                        });
                        // Prevent recursive embedding.
                        if (cellViewBelow && cellViewBelow.model.get('parent') !== cell.id) {
                            cellViewBelow.model.embed(cell);
                        }
                    }
                });
                graph.addCells([rect,rectGroup0,]);
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The paper event `cell:pointerup` is triggered for both elements and links.
2. `getBBox()` is not defined for links.

You are trying to call an undefined method `link.getBBox()` inside the `cell:pointerup` handler.

The solution can be either to check whether the `cellView` is an element and than proceed the reparenting or listen to `element:pointerup` instead (introduced in `jointjs` v0.9.4).

**v0.9.3**

```
paper.on('cell:pointerup', function (cellView, evt, x, y) {
    if (cellView.model.isLink()) return; // exit the handler when cell is a link
    // start reparenting
});
```

**v0.9.4+**

```
paper.on('element:pointerup', function (elementView, evt, x, y) {
    // start reparenting
});
```

Comment: When I try with first option. It says: `Uncaught TypeError: cellView.isLink is not a function` and with second option there's no error but reparenting is not working

Comment: Thanks a lot It worked with first option, but one quick question which is confusing: `what is difference between cell, cellView and elementView ? I think cell and element are same? and elementView is for rendering if I am not wrong so then what is the use of elementView inside a function`

Comment: Sir, Is there any documentation on adding ports to circle ?

Comment: `dia.Cell`, `dia.Element` and `dia.Link` are `Backbone.Model`s. `dia.CellView`, `dia.ElementView` and `dia.LinkView` are `Backbone.View`s. Cell is either Element or Link.

Comment: Could you please post another question regarding adding ports to the circle? I am not aware of a documentation for this.

Comment: Ok will do that. Thanks

Comment: Posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606999/how-to-add-ports-to-a-circle

Comment: I want to add links as well to the parent. My bad Sir I didn't check it. Its only adding shapes. How do I add links as well to parent?

Comment: Fixed it! Removing the fill color of white from rectangle worked

Comment: If the `cellView` is a link you can use `x`,`y` arguments to determine parent and then embed the link to the parent with `parent.embed(link)` I guess.

Comment: Links are shown behind the rectangle(parent) when adding to parent. How do I fix this?

Comment: Links are getting behind group rectangle. Here's the preview http://postimg.org/image/tn3ql559z/ How do I fix this? please help

Comment: I tried with the above method but I am not sure where exactly it has to go in the code

Comment: hello sir, posted a new question for the above problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667581/how-to-get-the-links-to-the-fronts-when-reparenting

Comment: Hello sir, could you please answer this question. I am facing problem while rendering json back from db to the view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794098/error-while-fetching-json-from-database