# How to add ports to a circle

Tags: jointjs

I am able to add ports to a rectangle using `joint.shapes.devs.Model` but the same is not working for a circle.

Here's what I have tried to add ports to circle:

```
var circle1 = new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
                            position: {x: 100, y: 225},
                            size: {width: 51, height: 51},
                            outPorts: [''],
                            attrs: {
                                '.': {magnet: true},
                                '.label': {text: '', 'ref-x': .4, 'ref-y': .2},
                                '.inPorts circle': {type: 'input'},
                                '.outPorts circle': {type: 'output'},
                                '.port-body': {r: 4}
                            }
                        });
                        graph.addCell(circle1);
```

I can see that Circle is created but with out ports. I couldn't find any documentation on this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example below shows how to define a circle element with rectangular ports.

```
joint.shapes.devs.CircleModel = joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend({

    markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><circle class="body"/></g><text class="label"/><g class="inPorts"/><g class="outPorts"/></g>',
    portMarkup: '<g class="port port<%= id %>"><rect class="port-body"/><text class="port-label"/></g>',

    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({

        type: 'devs.CircleModel',
        attrs: {
            '.body': { r: 50, cx: 50, stroke: 'blue', fill: 'lightblue' },
            '.label': { text: 'Circle Model', 'ref-y': 0.5, 'y-alignment': 'middle' },
            '.port-body': { width: 10, height: 10, x: -5, stroke: 'gray', fill: 'lightgray', magnet: 'active' }
        }

    }, joint.shapes.devs.Model.prototype.defaults)
});
```

It's important to tell the paper not to use default `dia.ElementView` for rendering but the `devs.ModelView` instead. To do that just define the view in the same namespace as the related model and add `"View"` at the end of model's name.

```
joint.shapes.devs.CircleModelView = joint.shapes.devs.ModelView;
```

Usage example:

```
var circleModel = new joint.shapes.devs.CircleModel({
    position: { x: 500, y: 100 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 100 },
    inPorts: ['a'],
    outPorts: ['b']
});
graph.addCell(circleModel);
```

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/gpfu7o4f/1/

Comment: `port<%= id %>` ?? Error at this line: cannot find symbol id

Comment: It displays only inPort. I cannot see outport...And for previous comment I changed `port<%= id %>` to `port<%= 1 %>` Is there any `guid()` function I can pass or I have write a loop for it?

Comment: Port ids are generated automatically. You should not change markup as you did. I've created a fiddle that shows that code above works. I suggest to update the jointjs to the latest version.

Comment: Where can I get 0.94 version of joint js. On official site download page, it showing 0.93

Comment: Updated to new version. Still outport is not visible and also `port<%=id%>` is throwing error as it is a jsp syntax. For example: I use  `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/joint.js"></script>`

Comment: The outport is not visible because you set all the port ids to `1`.  Try to comment the `portMarkup` and `.port-body` attrs If you don't require rectangular ports (http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/gpfu7o4f/2/). I can't help you with JSP syntax issue I'm afraid.

Comment: Can I store `"id"` in a variable? If possible then I can use that variable inside `port<%=VARIABLENAME%>`

Comment: Feel free to use a hack like this `<g class="port port' + ['<','%','='].join('') + ' id =>"><rect..' if that fools the JSP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84191/discussion-between-roman-and-kittu).

Comment: I think moving the js script into separate file should fix the problem