# How to get the links to the front when reparenting

Tags: jointjs

All the cells/elements are embedded on top of other cell but the links are hidden behind the element. How do I get the links on top of the element(parent)

Here's the [Preview](http://postimg.org/image/tn3ql559z)

I tried with `link.toFront()` which isn't working. Below is my code snippet:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function (cellView, evt, x, y) {

                    var cell = cellView.model;
                    if (!cell.get('embeds') || cell.get('embeds').length === 0) {
                        // Show the dragged element above all the other cells (except when the
                        // element is a parent).
                        cell.toFront();
                        link.toFront();

                    }

                    if (cell.get('parent')) {
                        graph.getCell(cell.get('parent')).unembed(cell);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bring a cell to the front with all connected links, try the following.

```
cell.toFront();
_.invoke(graph.getConnectedLinks(cell), 'toFront');
```

If you want to bring a parent cell with all its embedded cells to the front, call the `toFront` method with `deep: true` option. Method makes sure that all the descendants of the cell (embedded links and elements) are also brought to the front and no cell is hidden behind its parent (child `z` index is always higher than `z` index of child parent).

```
parent.toFront({ deep: true });
```

You can also checkout the `embeddingMode` and `validateEmbedding` paper options, that do the (un)embedding / validation automatically for you.

Documentation:

http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:toFront

http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper